# spring-cloud-stream3.0 batch-mode is true consumer data Can't convert value of class

Tags: serialization, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

config info

```yaml
spring:
  kafka:
    consumer:
      max-poll-records: 5
  cloud:
    stream:
      instance-count: 5
      instance-index: 0
      kafka:
        binder:
          brokers: 127.0.0.1:9092
          auto-create-topics: true
          auto-add-partitions: true
          min-partition-count: 5
      bindings:
        log-data-in:
          destination: log-data1
          group: log-data-group
          contenttype: text/plain
          consumer:
            partitioned: true
            batch-mode: true
        log-data-out:
          destination: log-data1
          contentType: text/plain
          producer:
            use-native-encoding: true
            partitionCount: 5
        #            configuration:
        #              key.serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
        #              value.serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer
```

send kafka code:

```java
LogData logData = new LogData();
logData.setId(1)
logData.setVer("22")
MessageChannel messageChannel = logDataStreams.outboundLogDataStreams(); 
      boolean sent = messageChannel.send(MessageBuilder.withPayload(logData).setHeader("partitionKey", key).build());
```

consumer data listener kafka topic

I think there is an error in processing the data type in kafka, there is no problem, there is no less setting, why is the conversion type error when consuming kafka information, bytes cannot know to convert an entity class

The code here is the consumption data, which is the place where the error is reported

```java
   @StreamListener(LogDataStreams.INPUT_LOG_DATA)
   public void handleLogData(List<LogData> messages) {
      System.out.println(messages);
      messages.parallelStream().forEach(item -> {
         System.out.println(item);
      });
 
   }
```

Define topic identifier

```java
public interface LogDataStreams {

   String INPUT_LOG_DATA = "log-data-in";
   String OUTPUT_LOG_DATA = "log-data-out";

   String INPUT_LOG_SC = "log-sc-in";
   String OUTPUT_LOG_SC = "log-sc-out";

   String INPUT_LOG_BEHAVIOR = "log-behavior-in";
   String OUTPUT_LOG_BEHAVIOR = "log-behavior-out";

   @Input(INPUT_LOG_DATA)
   SubscribableChannel inboundLogDataStreams();

   @Output(OUTPUT_LOG_DATA)
   MessageChannel outboundLogDataStreams();  

}
```

I think there is an error in processing the data type in kafka, there is no problem, there is no less setting, why is the conversion type error when consuming kafka information, bytes cannot know to convert an entity class

Error in last run:

```java
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Can't convert value of class  com.xx.core.data.model.LogData to class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer specified in value.serializer
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.xx.core.data.model.LogData cannot be cast to [B
```

Please help me, how to solve this problem

Comment: StreamListener and the whole annotation-based programming model has been deprecated for 3+ years and is being removed from a new version. Please migrate to  a functional programming model - https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/3.2.3-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_programming_model

Comment: Also i see that you are using native encoding `use-native-encoding: true`, which means s-c-stream will not be performing any conversion. Meanwhile your serializer/deserializers are commented out in configuration.